# JQuery's Datatable doesn't get initialized

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I'm currently building a MVC application with C#. I've used a Datatable in my user overview before, but when I want to use it in the detail page, in a partial view, it often doesn't load. Below I've copied the most important part of my DetailsGroup.cshtml file. While coding, I've basically copy/pasted from my working Overview page, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutWithoutNavBar.cshtml";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<html> 
....
<table id="myGroups">
....
</html>

@section scripts {
<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //onderstaand lijntje is om een deftige dataTable te initialiseren
        $('#myGroups').DataTable({
            "searching": false,
            "pageLength": 25
        });
    });

</script>
}
```

In my _LayoutWithoutNavBar.cshtml file I have the following bits of code:

```
<head>
    ...
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


</head>
<body role="document">
    <div id="mainBody" class="giveMeSomeSpace">
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

        @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
        @RenderBody()


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my main _Layout.cshtml file, which is also used in the Details page, I use the same scripts, described above. I don't know if a partial view can use those though, so I kinda copy/pasted to be sure.

EDIT: almost forgot. When I run the app, I don't get an error, the table just gets sloppily loaded, no functionality or css. If I open F12 on Chrome, I see a red *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function* If I click on that error, it sends me to the < head > tag of my main Details page

Comment: Where is you HTML for id = #myGroups

Comment: Any console errors???

Comment: added both table ID of html & console errors. Apologies.

Comment: Why are using html tag in your Partial View? And do you have the RenderSection In your _LayoutWithoutNavBar.cshtml for the Scripts?

Comment: I feel that you are trying to initialize something before loading the plugin. Say here you might be trying to initialize `DataTables` before `DataTable.js` has been loaded

Comment: The html tag might indeed be stupid of me. Gonna try and erease that. RenderSection is in both Layout.cshtml and LayoutWithoutNavBar.cshtml, the latter typed out above.  I think the order of things is fine though, I first do Datatable.js and then initialize the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. By using a mix of parents and partial views, I ended up using JQuery twice or even thrice. So presss F12 to check if you don't do that.